# Convert String "04-OCT-14 03.47.24.342000000 PM" to java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, datetime

```
String dateFromDb = "04-OCT-14 03.47.24.342000000 PM";
SimpleDateFormat datetimeFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
Date Date1 = datetimeFormatter1.parse(dateFromDb);
Timestamp fromTS1 = new Timestamp(Date1.getTime());
```

While converting this exception is thrown:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "04-OCT-14 03.47.24.342000000 PM" at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)

Can anyone help?

Comment: What makes you think that `04-OCT-14 03.47.24.342000000 PM` is parsable with `MMM dd,yyyy`?

Comment: Your pattern is wrong. Have a look at the [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: apart from your date format i don't think that there is any constructor of TimeStamp which accept only time

Comment: @amitbhardwaj what about [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp%28long%29)?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon ohh i searched other class which is in java.security.Timestamp. My mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dateformater configuration is wrong.

Use this pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat datetimeFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH.mm.ss.SSSSS aa",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

For more information see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of SimpleDateFormat